# Python argparse has a bug (?) with single character options arguments

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I have this code parsing command line arguments:

```
def handleCmdLineArgs(self):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-j','--juice', help='juice', default="")
    parser.add_argument('-bx','--box', help='box', default="")
    args,unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
```

When I run a command line with an argument that starts with j argparse AFTER the -j argument argparse will replace the -j argument with the remainder of the word:

Example:
program.py -j orange -jungle

argparse will return args.juice = "ungle" instead of the desired "orange"

I have created a workaround but I'm curious if anyone else has seen this or knows the reason why it is happening?  Or is this maybe a bug in argparse?

Answer (score 4):

This is expected behaviour. For single-dash options the space is optional. So these two are equivalent:

```
program.py -jorange
program.py -j orange
```

See the [*Option value syntax* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#option-value-syntax) of the documentation:

> For short options (options only one character long), the option and its value can be concatenated:
>
> ```
> >>> parser.parse_args(['-xX'])
> Namespace(foo=None, x='X')
> ```

If you want to pass in `orange -jungle` as the value, you need to use quoting on the command line:

```
program.py -j "orange -jungle"
```

If you want to pass in additional positional arguments that just happen to start with a `-`, use `--` to signal the end of the option flags:

```
program.py -j orange -- -jungle
```

See the [*Arguments containing -* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing):

> If you have positional arguments that must begin with `-` and don’t look like negative numbers, you can insert the pseudo-argument `'--'` which tells `parse_args()` that everything after that is a positional argument:
>
> ```
> >>> parser.parse_args(['--', '-f'])
> Namespace(foo='-f', one=None)
> ```

Comment: I don't want to pass in orange -jungle as the value, I want to pass in orange as the value of -j and I want -jungle to end up in unknown

Comment: @Ken: that's not an available option. Command lines should either accept an option or raise an error if it can't. You could perhaps try out [partial parsing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing) to implement handling 'unknown' options, but for any value that starts with a known single-character short option, you'll have to accept that argparse will treat that as an option-value pair.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters, That is exactly what I'm doing.  Note the line: args,unknown = parser.parse_known_args()

Comment: As I said, *but for any value that starts with a known single-character short option, you'll have to accept that argparse will treat that as an option-value pair*. You could try [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org), which apparently makes fewer assumptions about option parsing, to see if that doesn't treat `-j...` as a switch.